# Getting information for a graphics card in a Wayland session?

Tags: linux, xrandr, graphics, wayland, resolution

In the context of [generally](https://askubuntu.com/q/1165775/847449) troubleshooting Wayland, for this given graphics card:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

How would I determine the resolution it's [detecting](https://askubuntu.com/q/1460502/847449) as available for a given monitor?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ hwinfo --short
cpu:                                                            
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz, 3280 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz, 3275 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz, 3275 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz, 3247 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/event3    Colorado HP Wired Desktop 320K Keyboard
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      SiGma Micro Usb Mouse
monitor:
                       DELL E2422H
graphics card:
                       Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
sound:
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
storage:
                       Intel SATA Controller [RAID mode]
network:
  eno1                 Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
network interface:
  lxcbr0               Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  eno1                 Ethernet network interface
  virbr0               Ethernet network interface
  docker0              Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/sda             WDC WD2500AAKS-0
partition:
  /dev/sda1            Partition
  /dev/sda2            Partition
  /dev/sda3            Partition
  /dev/sda4            Partition
  /dev/sda5            Partition
cdrom:
  /dev/sr0             TSSTcorp DVD-ROM TS-H353C
usb controller:
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
                       Intel Q67 Express Chipset LPC Controller
                       Intel 82801 PCI Bridge
                       Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
hub:
                       Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
  /dev/lp0             Parallel controller
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller
                       Serial controller
  /dev/input/event5    Colorado HP Wired Desktop 320K Keyboard
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ hwprobe=bios.ddc.ports=4 hwinfo --monitor
16: None 00.0: 10000 Monitor                                    
  [Created at monitor.125]
  Unique ID: rdCR.cKFyiqA6N1F
  Parent ID: _Znp.xFWE_t6aB6C
  Hardware Class: monitor
  Model: "DELL E2422H"
  Vendor: DEL "DELL"
  Device: eisa 0xf136 "DELL E2422H"
  Serial ID: "B6VFTK3"
  Resolution: 720x400@70Hz
  Resolution: 640x480@60Hz
  Resolution: 640x480@75Hz
  Resolution: 800x600@60Hz
  Resolution: 800x600@75Hz
  Resolution: 1024x768@60Hz
  Resolution: 1024x768@75Hz
  Resolution: 1280x1024@75Hz
  Resolution: 1152x864@75Hz
  Resolution: 1280x1024@60Hz
  Resolution: 1600x900@60Hz
  Resolution: 1920x1080@60Hz
  Size: 527x296 mm
  Year of Manufacture: 2021
  Week of Manufacture: 52
  Detailed Timings #0:
     Resolution: 1920x1080
     Horizontal: 1920 2008 2052 2200 (+88 +132 +280) +hsync
       Vertical: 1080 1084 1089 1125 (+4 +9 +45) +vsync
    Frequencies: 148.50 MHz, 67.50 kHz, 60.00 Hz
  Driver Info #0:
    Max. Resolution: 1920x1080
    Vert. Sync Range: 50-75 Hz
    Hor. Sync Range: 30-83 kHz
    Bandwidth: 148 MHz
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #14 (VGA compatible controller)
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

(Wasn't sure on the syntax using `hwinfo` to get more info on the graphics card or above monitor.)

Somewhat random info from a Fedora [guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Wayland_problems#Identifying_the_session_type_in_runtime) and an online [man](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man8/hwinfo.8.html) page, but I'm more interested in how Wayland uses this information.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/wayland/comments/kuiqcl/xrandr_equivalent_on_wayland/